# Creating a trading strategy in Pine editor

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, trading, pine-script-v4

I have been trying to create a simple strategy in Trading view which consists of RSI - Relative strenght index and SMMA - Smoothed moving average  200. Signal to buy is when RSI is crossing oversold level (=30) upwards and at the same time price is above SMMA. Same goes vice versa for sell signal - RSI crossing overbought level (70) downwards and price is below SMMA.

The problem is that when I apply my strategy, in a chart is a Simple moving indicator SMA instead of Smoothed one. I am an absolute beginner, but I checked other strategies and they managed to use SMMA correctly.

Any ideas?

```
//@version=4
study(title="RSI and SMMA Cross Alert", shorttitle="RSI_SMMA_Alert", overlay=true)

// Inputs
rsiLength = input(14, title="RSI Length")
smmaLength = input(200, title="SMMA Length")
overboughtLevel = input(70, title="Overbought Level")
oversoldLevel = input(30, title="Oversold Level")

// Indicators
rsiValue = rsi(close, rsiLength)
smmaValue = sma(close, smmaLength)

// Conditions
longCondition = crossover(rsiValue, oversoldLevel) and close > smmaValue
shortCondition = crossunder(rsiValue, overboughtLevel) and close < smmaValue

// Plotting
plot(rsiValue, color=color.blue, title="RSI")
plot(smmaValue, color=color.red, title="SMMA 200")

// Alerts
alertcondition(longCondition, title="Long Alert", message="RSI crossed oversold level upwards and price is above SMMA 200")
alertcondition(shortCondition, title="Short Alert", message="RSI crossed overbought level downwards and price is below SMMA 200")
```